# Realm result value not assigning

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I want to know how I can use result variable for displaying and updating data. I monitor from realm browser my data is updated as I assign value and write to disk. I print value using **"po object"** in the console, and it prints values, but in the debugger, it only shows me default values.
Code Sample

```
let obj = SaloonServices.services[indexPath.section]

    cell.serviceLabel.text = obj.name
    cell.timeLabel.text = obj.time + " min"
    cell.priceLabel.text = "Price: " + obj.price + " SAR"


static var saloons: Results<SaloonCore>!
static func getSaloonFromCore() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            saloons = realm.objects(SaloonCore.self)
        }catch let error {
            print("realm Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the declaration of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Realm properties are declared as dynamic, and can only be read via the generated getter methods.  The Swift debugger cannot read dynamic properties, so will just show the default values for that data type.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#debugging

> Note that although the LLDB script allows inspecting the contents of your Realm variables in Xcode’s UI, this doesn’t yet work for Swift. Instead, those variables will show incorrect data. You should instead use LLDB’s po command to inspect the contents of data stored in a Realm.

Comment: I use this command and receive all my expected data, and now I need to update UI use same result in different places. There I got default value while assigning to UI. You can see class salooncore, it is inherited by realm object.